# Fallen Angels worshiped in ancient civilizations?

Tags: satan, angels, worship, pagan, gods

Ok, so I am doing research for a fictional book and in my research I have come across the names of 2 fallen angels ([book of Enoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Enoch)) that take advantage of mankind and allow man to worship them like god. Abezethibou (Egypt) and Nisroch (Babylon).

I realize that the book of Enoch isn't considered Canon to most Christian groups, but I'm wondering about similar recorded accounts recognized by any Christian groups, Scripture, or Deuterocanonical books?

My question is this: Are there other fallen angels that humans worshiped recorded or recognized as described above?

Answer (score 4):

In 1 Corinthians 10:19-20 (NIV), Paul writes:

> Do I mean then that a sacrifice offered to an idol is anything, or that an idol is anything? No, but the sacrifices of pagans are offered to demons, not to God, and I do not want you to be participants with demons.

This indicates that **all** idol worship is actually worship of demons (fallen angels).

2 Kings 3:26-27 (ESV) describes a human sacrifice which seems to be effective:

> When the king of Moab saw that the battle was going against him, he took with him 700 swordsmen to break through, opposite the king of Edom, but they could not. Then he took his oldest son who was to reign in his place and offered him for a burnt offering on the wall. And there came great wrath against Israel. And they withdrew from him and returned to their own land.

The fact that this sacrifice had such a dramatic effect seems to imply that the being to whom the sacrifice was directed existed and had power to influence a battle. Typical Christian theology identifies such gods as demons (fallen angels).

Comment: Don't Angels have no choice in the matter?  Where is the proof that they can disobey?